# jQuery combobox that allows custom entries to be typed

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I need to get this functionality: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

with this interface: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

As you can see, it's an autocomplete that allows me to click to drop down what auto-complete values are available, but also allows custom input.

I also need cross-browser and mobile compatibility.

Lastly, I really want to avoid a bloated package that includes hundreds of unneccessary capabilities.

This seems like it would be a common enough issue to have an available solution, but the only answers I can find are to modify jQueryUI (with instructions that seem out of date) or to use this package, with its huge set of includes:
http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxcombobox/index.htm

Is there a single-use plugin to accomplish this sort of input?

In minimal form, I don't even need autocomplete, just a select box that allows me to type custom entries.

Comment: Do the jqWidgets combo box.  It's not *that* much work to implement.  And it definitely allows custom entries.

Comment: @MattMc It's not so much a matter of work, it's just a large codebase, as well as a large number of HTTP requests, slowing down load times, especially for mobile users.  Also, I am hosting the files on an unstructured CDN, so multiple interacting includes add significantly to coderot.

Answer (score 1):

You can look the Chosen ComboBox, too. Link: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: Does Chosen allow custom entries?  If so, I can't find any mention of it in the docs.  At first glance, it looks like i'm limited to just filtering the existing choices.